# Amazon SNS multiple subscriptions of the same endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I noticed that if I try to create a subscription between a topic and a SQS queue twice, Amazon actually creates only a single one.

```
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:909420746768:bar --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:909420746768:foo --region=ap-southeast-2
{
    "SubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:909420746768:bar:39d8296e-18e3-4367-b10b-edd5af266f69"
}
```

-- if I call this command twice, the same SubscriptionArn is returned each time. If I call `list-subscriptions`, it will return a list with the single item too.

Cannot find the description of this behavior anywhere in Amazon's documentation, is it mentioned somewhere? Is it uniform across all protocols?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need multiple subscriptions?  The topic will deliver to the queue - do you want it to deliver multiple times?

Comment: @stdunbar I want to find a confirmation that multiple subscriptions are not allowed for all protocols, nothing more :)

Answer (score 0):

:)  This should be expected behaviour for notification.
 I confirmed it for JSON mail and mail type of end point. And multiple subscription through same endpoint ID (say from same email a@b.com) creates only on subscription.