# AWS SNS endpoint to topic subscription or filtering or multiple subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

This question is related, but I am unable to comment or upvote:
[Amazon SNS multiple subscriptions of the same endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016591/amazon-sns-multiple-subscriptions-of-the-same-endpoint)

Out of the example of the AWS doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html#message-filtering-example-policy-string-logic):

```
{
    "customer_interests": ["rugby"],
    "price_usd": [{"numeric":[">", 100]}]
}
```

I now derrive the following question: How would I set up the filter if an endpoint would like to subscribe to "rugby" with a price over 100 and also to "baseball" with a price below 200?

This overall OR logic is somehow missing in the documentation.

Therefore I thought of subscribing the same endpoint to the topic twice with different filter plicies. One with the filter for "rugby" and price over 100, and one subscription for "baseball" with a price below 200. This was kind of asked in the question of SO (link above).

Comment: Hi, Did you get the answer for this? I also have the same requirement where I've to apply the OR logic between message attributes and subscribe to same endpoint.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to implement the logic into my own app. There I stored the ARN. And then sending messages to multiple ARNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Nov 2023, SNS message filtering introduced support for the ‘OR’ operator. This new operator should be able to address your use case.

More information: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/11/amazon-sns-message-additional-filtering-operators/

Comment: Thank you for your upkeep of this issue. Unfortunately I have switched to a new company and do not have access to AWS anymore. So I cannot test this. But it is exactly what I was looking for back in the day. So I will, untested, mark this as the answer.